# Using OnClick event of Anchor Tag Retrieved Database Data using php

Tags: php, mysql, anchor

I want that if i click on an anchor tag it shows the mysql database table values

for example

```
 <a href"#">Click to show comments</a>

 after clicking

 it will do something like this

    SELECT * FROM `comments`LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), I advice you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this purpose.

using jquery you would have to do something like

in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="foobar "href="#">Click to show comments</a>
<div id="comments"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#id').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: "comment.php",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            foreach(v in data) {
              $('#comments').append(data[v]);
            }
          }
      });
   });
});
```

You would have to put together the comment.php script that would output the data retrieved from the database and use [json_encode](http://fr.php.net/json_encode) to encode it in JSON